# Incorrect Data Being Saved From AJAX Drop Down Menus

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I've been trying to sort out an issue I have with how one of my fields of data is being saved to a mySQL database. The issue I have is that instead of the text value being saved, the 'id' for the text value is being saved and I've no idea why.

The field is called 'detectorname' and the text value for this is selected via a drop down menu, which in turn, opens a second drop down menu called searchheadname. Both drop down menus are populated via PHP and AJAX scripts and show the correct text values when being selected by the user.

I appreciate that I haven't included any code, there is an awful lot and I have to admit I wasn't sure which sections would be of use.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps help me out with this please and let me know which parts of the code they would like me to post.

**UPDATE**

HTML Form & AJAX Script

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Location</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" 
        type="text/css" media="all" />  
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/addfindstolocation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            <!--
            function savedata() { 
            var userid =  document.getElementById("userid").value;
            var locationid = document.getElementById("locationid").value; 
            var searchheadid = document.getElementById("searchheadid").value;
            var additionalcomments = document.getElementById("additionalcomments").value;            

            var url = "addfindstolocationsave.php?userid=" + userid + "&locationid=" + locationid + "&searchheadid=" + searchheadid + "&additionalcomments=" + additionalcomments; 
            downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) { 
            }); 
            } 

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request.responseText, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {}

            function MM_callJS(jsStr) { //v2.0
            return eval(jsStr)
            }
            //-->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(function() {
            $( "#dateoftrip" ).datepicker({ 
            dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
            showOn: 'button',  
            buttonText: 'Select Date...'});
            });

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function AjaxFunction(detectorid)
            {
            var httpxml;
            try
            {
            // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
            // Internet Explorer
            try
            {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
            try
            {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
            }
            }
            }
            function stateck() 
            {
            if(httpxml.readyState==4)
            {

            var myarray=eval(httpxml.responseText);
            // Before adding new we must remove previously loaded elements
            for(j=document.addfindstolocation.searchheads.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
            document.addfindstolocation.searchheads.remove(j);
            }


            for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
            {
            var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
            optn.text = myarray[i];
            optn.value = myarray[i];
            document.addfindstolocation.searchheads.options.add(optn);

            } 
            }
            }
            var url="searchheaddetails.php";
            url=url+"?detectorid="+detectorid;
            url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
            httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
            httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
            httpxml.send(null);
            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form name="addfindstolocation" method='POST'>
                    <p><label></label>
                    </p>
                    <p align="left">
                        <input name="userid" type="text" id="userid" value="1"/>
                        <input name="locationid" type="text" id="locationid"  value="2"/>
                        <br />
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            <div align="left">Click on the map to place the marker for the find that has been made and drag until the precise location has been found. </div>
                        </div>
                            <p align="left"><label>Find OSGB36 Latitude Co-ordinate<br />
                                </label>
                            </p>
                            <div>
                                <div align="left">
                                    <input name="findosgb36lat" type="text" id="findosgb36lat" size="20" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p align="left"><label>Find OSGB36 Longitude Co-ordinate<br />
                                </label>
                            </p>
                            <div>
                                <div align="left">
                                    <input name="findosgb36lon" type="text" id="findosgb36lon" size="20" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p align="left"><label>Date of Trip<br />
                                </label>
                            </p>
                            <div>
                                <div align="left">
                                    <input name="dateoftrip" type="text" id="dateoftrip" size="10" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p align="left"><label>Find Category</label>&nbsp;</p>
                            <div>
                                <div align="left">
                                    <?php
                                    mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password") or die("Connection Failed");
                                    mysql_select_db("dbname")or die("Connection Failed");
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM findcategories";
                                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                                    ?>
                                    <select name="findcategory" id="findcategory">
                                        <option value=''>Select One</option>
                                        <?php
                                        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $line['findcategory'];?>"> <?php echo $line['findcategory'];?> </option>

                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>    
                                </div>
                                <p align="left">
                                    <label>Find Name<br />
                                    </label>
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <input name="findname" type="text" id="findname" size="35" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p align="left">
                                    <label>Find Description<br />
                                    </label>
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <input name="finddescription" type="text" id="finddescription" size="150" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p align="left"><label></label>
                                    <label>Detector Used</label></p>
                                <div>
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <select name=detectors id="detectorid" onchange="AjaxFunction(this.value);">
                                            <option value=''>Select One</option>
                                            <?
                                            require "phpfile.php";// connection to database 
                                            $q=mysql_query("SELECT * from detectors WHERE userid='1'ORDER BY 'detectorname' ASC");
                                            while($n=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
                                            echo "<option value=$n[detectorid]>$n[detectorname]</option>";
                                            }

                                            ?>
                                      </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p align="left">
                                    <label></label>
                                    <label>Search Head Used</label></p>
                                <div>
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <select name=searchheads id="searchheadid">
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p align="left">
                                    <label>Detector Settings</label>
                                    <label><br />
                                    </label>
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <textarea name="detectorsettings" cols="50" rows="12" id="detectorsettings"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p align="left">
                                    <label>PAS Ref. (if known)<br />
                                    </label>
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <input name="pasref" type="text" id="pasref" size="9" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p align="left"><label>Additional Comments</label>
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <div align="left">
                                        <textarea name="additionalcomments" cols="50" rows="12" id="additionalcomments"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p align="left"><br />
                                    <label></label>
                                </p>
                                <p align="left">
                                    <input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="MM_callJS('savedata()')" value="Submit" />        
                                </form>
                                    <div id="map"></div>
                                </body>
                                </html>



**'Searchheadetails.php' File (Called in file above)**     

     <?
$detectorid=$_GET['detectorid'];
require "config.php";
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchheads WHERE detectorid='$detectorid' ORDER BY 'searchheadname' ASC");
echo mysql_error();
$myarray=array();
$str="";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$str=$str . "\"$nt[searchheadname]\"".",";
}
$str=substr($str,0,(strLen($str)-1)); // Removing the last char , from the string
echo "new Array($str)";

?>
```

Comment: One thing you should do is inspect the HTTP transaction to see what the browser is sending to the server. You can do that with a tool like the "Network" tab in the Chrome developer tools, or with Firebug or Tamper Data in Firefox.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. I must admit to being fairly new to this. Could you tell me please are the pieces of software you suggest easy to use? Kind regards. Chris

Comment: Well, it's not the easiest thing in the world, but if you're going to be doing this kind of work to any significant extent you'll be perpetually confused and confounded if you don't learn them. The "Network" tab in Chrome is probably the easiest to use, though Tamper Data for Firefox is also pretty simple (if a little ugly). The important thing they let you do is examine the HTTP request contents as they actually looked when the browser sent them to the server. It helps to separate server problems from client problems!

Comment: Hi, I've been working on the files and I've found out that they are working as they should. What I would like to do though is to change the value that is saved into the mySQl database. I've added the code to my original post, but basically for the second drop down menu called 'searchheads' I would like to keep the text value for the user to select, but instead of saving the text value, I would like to save the 'id' value instead. I just wondered if it was at all possible that somoene could perhaps show me please what I need to change to get this to work. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the `detectorid` to `detectorname` in one line of the code below:

```
<div>
<div align="left">
<select name=detectors id="detectorid" onchange="AjaxFunction(this.value);">
<option value=''>Select One</option>
<?
require "phpfile.php";// connection to database 
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * from detectors 
  WHERE userid='1'ORDER BY 'detectorname' ASC");
while($n=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo "<option value=$n[detectorname]>$n[detectorname]</option>";
//***I changed the line above***  TODO:Remove this comment
}
?>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. I've tried your suggestion and unfortunately it doesn't give the result I'm looking for. Changing the field from 'detectorid' to 'detectorname' means that there are no values in the second drop down menu. I think that the change needs to be in this line of the second php file: str=$str . "\"$nt[searchheadname]\"".","; but I'm not sure what to change. Could you tell me please have you any ideas? Many thanks once again and kind regards. Chris